# Large Command Error with unbalanced brackets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can't find it anywhere, literally been looking for over 2 hours, i've checked each indivual command and the overall json. Nothing.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Using MC 1.8.9

**Edit 2:** This is the error i receive when i put it in a command block and click on any of the four buttons (North, East, South or West):

[image: ScreenShot]

```
tellraw @p [{"text":"Kilo's Cannons\n","color":"aqua"},{"text":"North","bold":"true","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,Block:\"stone_button\",Data:5,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:minecraft:dispenser,Data:2,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:0b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:1b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:2b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:3b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:12b,Slot:4b}, {id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:5b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:6b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:7b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:8b}]}}}"}},{"text":" : ","bold":"true","color":"aqua"},{"text":"East","bold":"true","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,Block:\"stone_button\",Data:5,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:minecraft:dispenser,Data:5,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:0b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:1b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:2b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:3b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:12b,Slot:4b}, {id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:5b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:6b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:7b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:8b}]}}}"}},{"text":" : ","bold":"true","color":"aqua"},{"text":"South","bold":"true","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,Block:\"stone_button\",Data:5,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:minecraft:dispenser,Data:3,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:0b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:1b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:2b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:3b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:12b,Slot:4b}, {id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:5b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:6b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:7b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:8b}]}}}"}},{"text":" : ","bold":"true","color":"aqua"},{"text":"West","bold":"true","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,Block:\"stone_button\",Data:5,Riding:{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:minecraft:dispenser,Data:4,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:0b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:1b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:2b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:3b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:12b,Slot:4b}, {id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:5b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:6b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:7b},{id:\"minecraft:fire_charge\",Count:11b,Slot:8b}]}}}"}}]
```

Comment: No, wait, despite the misleading title, this is actually valid JSON, but the command inside is for a really old version of Minecraft. Are you actually playing <1.9?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I pasted this into sublime text, and noted that there are an equal number of left and right brackets of both types. Furthermore, all the pairs seem to be in reasonable places.

Comment: This question may help you: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207989/unbalanced-curly-brackets-error-with-this-command-block-code-what-am-i-doing

Comment: I've unfortunately already flagged the post, but ... Possible duplicate of [Data tag parsing failed: unbalanced quotation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286404/data-tag-parsing-failed-unbalanced-quotation#comment403548_286404)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [I need help with this Minecraft Tellraw command, Issue at column 89](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221833/i-need-help-with-this-minecraft-tellraw-command-issue-at-column-89)

Answer (score 4):

## I Believe I found the issue

When you use tell raw it execute the action as the player, this includes the character limit. I tested it and they both cut off at the same point in the error and when you paste it in chat.